# How to close the gap in this coat?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices, object-mode

I have this coat modeled and need to close this gap but not sure how. The "fill" option doesn't seem to work and mirror is not an option most likely.

[image]

[image]

What it looks like when I use "fill"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can select the 2 opposite edges and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*:

[image]